# Float image to left of centered text

Tags: html, css

I currently have some text that is left aligned but centered as follows:

```
<div class="center-text">There is some text here</div>
<div class="center-text">There is also some other text here</div>
<div class="center-text">Finally there is some text here</div>

.center-text {
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

How can I float an image to the left of the text that is in the bottom right corner?  What I'm looking for is the following:

[image: Desired behavior]

The black frame is the surrounding div, the red is the image and the text is as described above.  My text is currently behaving as expected but I can't seem to add the image without impacting the text.

Comment: You may just want to position the image absolutely instead.

Answer (score 0):

I made it a little bit different:

```css
.container{
    height: 300px;
    position:relative;
    border: 30px solid black; 
}
.center-text {
    width: 100%; 
}
p {
    margin: 0;
}
img{
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width:30%;
}
.text{
    float: right;
    width: 65%;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="center-text">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRLwIM4lLwdmXvvYio988Z70kxTBtoNudITd9_72iGRjlusoVey" />
        <div class="text">
            <p>There is some text here</p>
            <p>There is also some other text here</p>
            <p>Finally there is some text here</p>
            <p>Finally there is some text here</p>
            <p>Finally there is some text here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope it also helps you :)